# Photoshop "Diffuse Glow" Not working Properly

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, image-filter

Since a last couple of days, the Diffuse Glow Filter in my Photoshop CS4 ext(x86). has been behaving oddly. Instead of filling with white glow, it now fills with 'pale blue'.

I don't think I have changed any photoshop specific settings for this to happen.

How do I revert the diffuse glow filter back to its good old self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have white selected as the background color. You can press "D" on your keyboard or click on the small chit above the color panels on the bottom of the tool panel.

[image]

Comment: Holy Smokes! Thanks a lot! Got fixed in a snap!